# Heredar de hijo un atributo (width)

Tags: html, css

soy el Dr. Nick

Y os traigo una pregunta un tanto engorrosa, ¿cómo puedo hacer que un `div` herede la anchura(`Width`) de un hijo en concreto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito que el `div` herede el `width` del `p` pequeño, y siempre pilla la del grande.

Nota, no puedo modificar el tamaño del `div` grande por motivos que me pide la empresa.

Os adjunto el código que tengo:

```
<div>
<h5>
    <div style="display: inherit;">
        <p>Texto tochisimo</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

El código es un ejemplo ilustrativo, no os lo toméis al pie de la letra.

Answer (score 5):

Los [`div`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/div) son elementos de bloque, por lo que si necesitas que **no ocupe el ancho completo de su contenedor**, puedes cambiar su [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/display) a, por ejemplo, `inline-block`.

De esa forma conseguirás que su ancho se adapte a su contenido.

#### Ejemplo:

```css
.main {
  background-color: #0c0;
  padding: 8px;
}
.container {
  background-color: #c00;
  display: inline-block;
}
.container p {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <p>Texto</p>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div class="container">
    <p>Texto tochisimo</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes asignar el tamaño del `p` pequeño al `div` contenedor con javascript

```js
function resize(){
  let panelPadre = document.getElementById("padre");
  let panelHijo = document.getElementById("peque");
  panelPadre.style.width=`${panelHijo.clientWidth}px`;
}
resize();
```

```css
#padre{background-color:red;}
#peque{background-color:blue;width:200px;}
#grande{background-color:green;width:500px;}
```

```html
<div id="padre">
    <div id="peque" style="display: inherit;">
        <p>Texto</p>
    </div>
    <div id="grande" style="display: inherit;">
        <p>Texto tochisimo</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Espero que te sirva.